# How do you update a Glass CardScrollView programatically in XE16 (KitKat)?

Tags: google-glass

How do you update a Glass CardScrollView programatically in XE16 (KitKat)?

I have a CardScrollView of cards that display photos from url's.  I download the photos from the url's in a background thread and then I want to "refresh" or update the CardScrolView to make the cards display the new images.

I was calling:

```
cardScrollView.updateViews(true);
```

In XE12, but in XE16/KitKat that operation is deprecated.  So how do you download an image in the background and then update a displayed "Card" with that image?  Just calling card.addImage() seems to add a blank image and doesn't display the image.

I've updated my call from the background thread to be:

```
cardScrollView.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Here is the code for the card scroll adapter with

```
private class SpecialCardsScrollAdapter extends CardScrollAdapter {

    @Override
    public int getPosition(Object item) {
        return specialCardsList.indexOf(item);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return specialCardsList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return specialCardsList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        return specialCardsList.get(position).getView();
    }

}
```

Should I expect that calling cardScrollView.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged(); would cause Cards already put into the scrollview to update the image they have stored?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in the [release notes](https://developers.google.com/glass/release-notes), use  [BaseAdapter#notifyDataSetChanged()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged%28%29) from your `CardScrollAdapter` instead.

Comment: How do you invoke that syntax?  Are you casting the cardScrollView to Base Adapter?  Can you give a code sample?

Comment: The `CardScrollAdapter` extends the `BaseAdapter` class: call this method from your adapter, not your view.

Comment: ok, even with that call the images on the existing cards aren't being updated.